# Second approval

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have a custom object, my requirement is whenever a user update or add or delete the object record, they need second approval for that from another user or manager, can we achieve this by standard approval process

Comment: I guess no, You can go with before trigger and submit that record for Approval process

Comment: Approval processes are usually trigger when records are manually submit for approval. For automating it you can try using process builder, but I don't think it supports delete event. Otherwise you may have to write a trigger.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your response, i ll try to figure it out

Comment: I already used process builder to initialise the approval process, it is working fine but i m stuck at second approval now